# How to avoid onPress function works inside the inner Views in React-Native

Tags: react-native, view, touchablewithoutfeedback

I want to avoid the `onPress={() => onRequestClose()}` function working inside the inner `View` in my react-native project.

While user click on the screen the (whatever the area) `onPress={() => onRequestClose()}` works, to avoid that I use `View` inside the 1st `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and inside the `View` component I added another `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. But this is not working.

I'm struggling to find the solution, Is there any method to resolve this matter.

My code as follows

```
<View style={styles.videoOverlayWrapper}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onRequestClose()} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <View><TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{}}>{props.children}</TouchableWithoutFeedback></View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass null in any onPress, as onPress={() => null} or onPress={null}

```
<View style={styles.videoOverlayWrapper}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => null} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
</View>
```